# Debugging Plotly: running code while stepping through debug mode v running code at console while in debug mode

Tags: r, plotly

I'm attempting to debug a function that combines a boilerplate plotly with some user inputs to create a plotly graph.
I'm finding an extremely puzzling and inexplicable behavior of plotly that I am clueless as to how to remedy.
When I step into the function with the debugger and use the Enter key or "n" to step forward and run the code, then type `.p` at the console I get the following graph:
[Running while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbtWF.jpg)

I've tried using `plotly_build(.p)` but the result is the same.

However, if I simply highlight the same code while still in debugging mode and run it, then type `.p` at the console I get the following graph:
[Running from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhh6h.jpg)

The environment, and inputs are the same, but for some reason the graph renders when I run it by hand but does not when I run it using the debugger. Does anyone have any ideas why this behavior happens and how to remedy it?
I'm unable to debug the function rendering a blank graph if it appears to just do so for no apparent reason other than that the code happens to be inside a function rather than run directly.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Here's a reprex:

```
rep_data <- structure(
  list(
    ProjectRegion = c(
      "14",
      "14",
      "14",
      "14",
      "14",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "4",
      "4",
      "4",
      "4",
      "4",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "16",
      "14",
      "14",
      "14",
      "4"
    ),
    ProjectCounty = c(
      "Butler",
      "Butler",
      "Butler",
      "Butler",
      "Clermont",
      "Clinton",
      "Clinton",
      "Fayette",
      "Fayette",
      "Highland",
      "Lorain",
      "Lorain",
      "Lorain",
      "Lorain",
      "Lorain",
      "Pickaway",
      "Pickaway",
      "Ross",
      "Ross",
      "Ross",
      "Warren",
      "Warren",
      "Warren",
      "Wayne"
    ),
    FriendlyProjectName = c(
      "FPE",
      "CoH",
      "C",
      "HH",
      "JSHS",
      "CCSCCHSEO",
      "CHS",
      "BH",
      "CACoFC",
      "CHS",
      "CCCSECEO",
      "SECE",
      "THC",
      "VHG",
      "WCP",
      "G",
      "H",
      "RCCMSEO",
      "MS",
      "SoHJH",
      "BP",
      "IHN",
      "T",
      "SAS"
    ),
    Days = c(
      16.2359393218663,
      9.7255318073283,
      4.1680035263981,
      13.0951995354621,
      3.60546653063087,
      6.11011230494265,
      9.71422679723695,
      8.98144658548659,
      15.4830757510789,
      14.4081379099974,
      16.528719553729,
      10.138851540768,
      4.73515009314699,
      4.58016183327701,
      10.6360782999525,
      10.0814923191527,
      7.57516541911099,
      13.81556961144,
      12.7836893932979,
      4.14872018703038,
      15.6819862791159,
      4.52603938253064,
      2.49904878973803,
      16.7113243384609
    ),
    hover = c(
      "g",
      "t",
      "c",
      "h",
      "l",
      "h",
      "c",
      "j",
      "k",
      "f",
      "k",
      "v",
      "n",
      "w",
      "j",
      "o",
      "l",
      "t",
      "u",
      "n",
      "p",
      "q",
      "a",
      "i"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -24L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
rep_plotly <- function(.data, x = ~ FriendlyProjectName, y = ~ Percent) {
  # If no data return no graph
  if (nrow(.data) < 1) return(NULL)
  .p <- plotly::plot_ly(
    .data,
    x = rlang::enexpr(x),
    y = rlang::enexpr(y),
    text = ~ hover,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    type = "bar"
  )
  return(.p)
}
debugonce(rep_plotly)
rep_plotly(rep_data, y = ~ Days)
```

I'm running RStudio 1.3.959.
Here's my SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5      dplyr_1.0.0       shiny_1.5.0.9000 
[4] Rminor_0.0.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2             pkgload_1.1.0          tidyr_1.1.0           
 [4] jsonlite_1.7.1         viridisLite_0.3.0      R.utils_2.9.2         
 [7] here_0.1               assertthat_0.2.1       yaml_2.2.1            
[10] remotes_2.2.0          pillar_1.4.6.9000      backports_1.1.6       
[13] lattice_0.20-38        glue_1.4.2             digest_0.6.25.1       
[16] promises_1.1.1.9000    colorspace_1.4-1       R.oo_1.23.0           
[19] htmltools_0.5.0.9001   httpuv_1.5.4.9000      pkgconfig_2.0.3       
[22] config_0.3             purrr_0.3.4.9000       xtable_1.8-4          
[25] scales_1.1.1.9000      processx_3.4.2         later_1.1.0.9000      
[28] tibble_3.0.3.9000      styler_1.3.1.9000      generics_0.0.2        
[31] ggplot2_3.3.2          usethis_1.6.3          ellipsis_0.3.1        
[34] DT_0.15                withr_2.3.0            lazyeval_0.2.2        
[37] cli_2.0.2              crayon_1.3.4           mime_0.9              
[40] ps_1.3.4               R.methodsS3_1.8.0      golem_0.3.0           
[43] fs_1.4.1.9000          dockerfiler_0.1.3      fansi_0.4.1           
[46] R.cache_0.14.0         xml2_1.3.2             pkgbuild_1.1.0        
[49] shinydashboard_0.7.1   rsconnect_0.8.16       tools_3.5.3           
[52] data.table_1.13.0      prettyunits_1.1.1      lifecycle_0.2.0.9000  
[55] stringr_1.4.0          plotly_4.9.0           munsell_0.5.0         
[58] HMIS_0.0.0.9000        callr_3.4.4            packrat_0.5.0         
[61] compiler_3.5.3         rlang_0.4.7.9000       grid_3.5.3            
[64] attempt_0.3.1          rstudioapi_0.11        htmlwidgets_1.5.1.9001
[67] crosstalk_1.1.0.1      shinyWidgets_0.5.0.920 testthat_2.3.2        
[70] gtable_0.3.0           roxygen2_7.1.1         R6_2.4.1              
[73] zoo_1.8-8              lubridate_1.7.9        knitr_1.29.3          
[76] fastmap_1.0.1          utf8_1.1.4             rprojroot_1.3-2       
[79] desc_1.2.0             stringi_1.5.4          Rcpp_1.0.5.2          
[82] vctrs_0.3.2            tidyselect_1.1.0       xfun_0.18.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I overcomplicated the passing of arguments to `plot_ly`. `x` and `y` can be passed as is and the formula format will be retained. `rlang::enexpr` was attaching the external environment to the `x` formula and making it such that FriendlyProjectName was searched for in an environment other than that of the data, making for a blank graph.

The working function is simply:

```
rep_plotly <- function(.d, x = ~ FriendlyProjectName, y = ~ Percent) {
  # If no data return no graph
  if (nrow(.d) < 1) return(NULL)
  .p <- plotly::plot_ly(
    data = .d,
    x = x,
    y = y,
    text = ~ hover,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    type = "bar"
  )
  return(.p)
}
```